# copy custom attribute from quote_address to sales_order_address not working

Tags: checkout, magento2.2

I created an sms attribute and added sms column into quote_address and sales_order_address database tables.

I am using [this](https://github.com/arvindporiya/poriyabrother) extension for the custom attribute.

After click on next on checkout shipping information, it adds value into sms column of quote_address database table for shipping but it is not working for sales_order_address.

P.s fieldset.xml is not working.
Any help please.

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. You can try the following way:

> app/code/EdmondsCommerce/Sms/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="sr_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="EdmondsCommerce\Sms\Observer\SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/EdmondsCommerce/Sms/Observer/SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore.php

```
<?php
namespace EdmondsCommerce\Sms\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote');
        $shippingAddressData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        if (isset($shippingAddressData['sms'])) {
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setSms($shippingAddressData['sms']);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sohel, i applied same and its working. Now i can see value of sms at all the place by edited address template.

Comment: how does this observer work?

Comment: I get NULL after following this

Comment: same issue it adds value into sms column of quote_address database table for shipping but it is not working for sales_order_address.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way is to do it via plugin.
In etc/di.xml add

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress">
    <plugin name="split_shipping_convert_address" type="{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress"/>
</type>
```

and than create class

```
<?php    

namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Quote\Address;


class ToOrderAddress
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress $subject
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface $orderAddress
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $object
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface
     */
    public function afterConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface $orderAddress,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $object
    ) {
        $orderAddress->setSms($object->getSms());
        return $orderAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.